# Is Firefox using frame interpolation now?

Tags: firefox, youtube, framerate

Until recently I have only seen motion interpolation in Chrome.

However, since 50.1 it seems some YouTube videos are frame interpolated.

Is this a Firefox feature, or is Flash/YouTube doing frame interpolation on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube has a new 720p60 resolution that is apparently a true 60 FPS data stream, so it is not interpolated.